# FIR Filter, Sampling frequency vs bandwidth

Tags: filtering, signal-processing, sampling

In a FIR filter the ratio between the bandwidth and the sampling frequency is costant?
I mean, if I use the same coefficients but with the double Fs, will I have also double BW?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the filter characteristics are normalised with respect to the sample rate, so if you double the sample rate then every frequency parameter for the filter such as cut-off points, bandwidth, etc, will also be doubled.